# How to dbms_output.put_line in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

The result doesn't show the command `ROUND(SYSDATE - V_FECHA,1)` by `dbms_output.put_line`, I have this script:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
    v_fecha   v$database.created%TYPE;
BEGIN
    CASE
        WHEN ( SYSDATE - v_fecha <= 50 ) THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('LA FECHA DE CREACION DE LA BASE DE DATOS ES <= 50 DÍAS');
        WHEN ( SYSDATE - v_fecha > 50 AND SYSDATE - v_fecha <= 100 ) THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('LA FECHA DE CREACIÓN ES MAYOR QUE 50 DÍAS O <= 100 DÍAS');
        ELSE
            dbms_output.put_line('LA FECHA DE CREACIÓN ES IGUAL A '
                                   || round(SYSDATE - v_fecha,1)
                                   || ' DÍAS');
    END CASE;
END;
/
```

---

```
OUTPUT:
LA FECHA DE CREACIÓN ES IGUAL A  DÍAS.
```

*Oracle Version: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
IDE: SQL DEVELOPER - Versión 4.1.1.19*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to fetch from `v$database`. Add this after `BEGIN`

```
SELECT
    created
INTO v_fecha
FROM
    v$database;
```

Comment: Thank very much @Kaushik I add the select.

Answer (score 2):

The output of the command `ROUND(SYSDATE - V_FECHA,1)` is not shown, because `V_FECHA` is still `NULL` in your code. You can verify that with

```
SELECT ROUND(SYSDATE - NULL) FROM DUAL;
```

which doesn't show anything, too. Nearly every operation in SQL will output `NULL` if the input contains `NULL` values, and `DBMS_OUTPUT` shows then an empty string.

As @Kaushik suggested, if you add the `SELECT` to your code, and maybe something that catches `NULL` values, everything should be fine:

```
DECLARE
  v_fecha v$database.created%TYPE;
  delta NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT created INTO v_fecha FROM v$database;
  delta := v_fecha - SYSDATE;

  CASE WHEN delta <= 50 THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('LA FECHA DE CREACION DE LA BASE DE DATOS ES <= 50 DÍAS');
       WHEN delta > 50 AND delta <= 100 THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('LA FECHA DE CREACIÓN ES MAYOR QUE 50 DÍAS O <= 100 DÍAS');
       WHEN delta IS NULL THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('LA FECHA DE CREACIÓN ES DESCONOCIDA');
       ELSE 
          dbms_output.put_line('LA FECHA DE CREACIÓN ES IGUAL A '
                               || NVL(round(SYSDATE - v_fecha,1), 0)
                               || ' DÍAS');
  END CASE;
END;
/
```

I put in two options, `WHEN delta IS NULL` and `NVL` to show you different possibilities.

Furthermore I try to call `SYSDATE` only once, as every call of `SYSDATE` might be slightly later than the previous one. (The difference is of course very little, but I am trying to prevent errors which occur very rarely but are then very difficult to find.)

Comment: Thanks very much @wolφi, I add the SELECT- output success.